# xgboost model prediction error : Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-sagemaker

I have a model that's trained locally and deployed to an engine, so that I can make inferences / invoke endpoint. When I try to make predictions, I get the following exception.

```
raise ValueError('Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional')
ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional
```

My `model` is a xgboost model with some pre-processing (variable encoding) and hyper-parameter tuning. Code to train the model:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 


# split df into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.iloc[:,0:21], df.iloc[:,-1], test_size=0.1)

X_train.shape
(1000,21)

# Encode categorical variables  
cat_vars = ['cat1','cat2','cat3']
cat_transform = ColumnTransformer([('cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_vars)], remainder='passthrough')

encoder = cat_transform.fit(X_train)
X_train = encoder.transform(X_train)
X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)

X_train.shape
(1000,420)

# Define a xgboost regression model
model = XGBRegressor()

# Do hyper-parameter tuning
.....

# Fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here's what `model` object looks like:

```
XGBRegressor(colsample_bytree=xxx, gamma=xxx,
             learning_rate=xxx, max_depth=x, n_estimators=xxx,
             subsample=xxx)
```

My test data is a string of float values which is turned into an array as the data must be passed as numpy array.

```
testdata = [........., 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2000, 200, 85, 412412, 123, 41, 552, 50000, 512, 0.1, 10.0, 2.0, 0.05]
```

I have tried to reshape the numpy array from 1d to 2d, however, that doesn't work as the number of features between test data and trained model do not match.

My question is how do I pass a numpy array same as the length of # of features in trained model? Any work around ideas? I am able to make predictions by passing test data as a list locally.

More info on inference script here: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/blob/main/xgboost_script_mode_local_training_and_serving/code/inference.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/ml/code/inference.py", line 75, in predict_fn
prediction = model.predict(input_data)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 448, in predict
test_dmatrix = DMatrix(data, missing=self.missing, nthread=self.n_jobs)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 404, in __init__
self._init_from_npy2d(data, missing, nthread)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 474, in _init_from_npy2d
raise ValueError('Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional')
ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional
```

When I attempt to reshape the test data to 2d numpy array, using `testdata.reshape(-1,1)`, I run into `feature_names` mismatch exception.

```
File "/opt/ml/code/inference.py", line 75, in predict_fn
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  |     prediction = model.predict(input_data)
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 456, in predict
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  |     validate_features=validate_features)
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 1284, in predict
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  |     self._validate_features(data)
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 1690, in _validate_features
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  |     data.feature_names))
3n0u6hucsr-algo-1-qbiyg  | ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15',
```

Update: I can retrieve the feature names for the model by running `model.get_booster().feature_names`. Is there a way I can use these names and assign to test data point so that they are consistent?

```
['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5',......'f417','f418','f419']
```

Comment: How you trained your model (probably using some `fit` function)? For prediction you must provide input_data with the same features you used during training. And for single test sample, input_data must have shape (1, -1)

Comment: @dankal444 correct, I checked that # of features used to train the model as same as number of features in test data sample. When I reshape the `numpy array` to `(1,-1)`, I run into `feature mismatch exception`. I updated the question with more info on training the model and the exception.

Comment: In your question there is no info about how exactly you prepare `input_data`? Do you use `encoder.transform()` as you do for training data?

Comment: @dankal444 yes, the same `encoder` is used to for sample test data point as well.

Comment: @dankal444 also, I can get the feature names for the model by running - `model.get_booster().feature_names`. Is there a way I can use these names and assign the test data so that they remain consistent?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is to provide the test data as the same data type as the train data.

Thank you for the comment. With the added information that after encoding the datatype of `X_train` is `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` and `y_train` is a `Pandas series`. If there are no memory constrains we can transform both to numpy array by using:

```
model.fit(X_train.toarray(), y_train.to_numpy())
```

Reference to:

- scipy manual: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html
- pandas manual: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html

Comment: agreed that the data type needs to be the same. After the encoding step, my `X_train` is of `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` type and `y_train` is a `Pandas series`. My preferred way is to use `numpy array` all around.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried to train with numpy array and also pass a numpy array for single point prediction, however, I am running into `feature name mismatch issue`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217519/error-invoking-xgboost-endpoint-deployed-locally-feature-names-mismatch

Comment: Also, we can use the chat room if that's ok: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239894/xgboost-0-90-issues

Comment: I'm having this prediction model error with LightGDM model and have posted my error on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894373/lightgbm-prediction-issue-valueerror-input-numpy-ndarray-or-list-must-be-2-dime

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
model.predict(np.array([[x1, x2, x3]]))
```

where x1, x2, x3 are your features and model your xgboost_model.